# Algorithm Challenge number formatting problem

Tags: ruby, algorithm

Invoice numbers are numeric only with any number of digits. To format one correctly, group the digits in group of three plus a group of any remainder, but never leave one digit by itself, unless it's a one digit number. Eg these are all correct formatting

- 123
- 12-34
- 6
- 783-907-23-45

And these are not

- 123-4
- 98-456

There's one more catch user input is passed directly to the function and you never know what characters users might type. Ignore any part of the input that is not digit

Invoice.format_number should always return a string

```
module Invoice
  def self.format_number(str)
     return ""
  end
end

puts Invoice.format_number("ab1234")
```

What I have tried

1st approach

```
arr = []
str.chars.each do |elem|
  val = elem =~ /\A[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+\Z/
  arr << elem if val == 0
end

num_of_digits = arr.length
pairs_of_two = 0
pairs_of_three = 0


if num_of_digits > 5
  while num_of_digits > 0 do
    break if num_of_digits <= 3
    if num_of_digits >= 3 && (num_of_digits % 3 == 0  || num_of_digits % 3 == 2)
      pairs_of_three += 1
      num_of_digits -= 3
    elsif num_of_digits % 2 == 0 || num_of_digits % 2 == 1
      pairs_of_two += 1
      num_of_digits -= 2
    end
  end
end
```

2nd approach

```
arr = []
str.chars.each do |elem|
  val = elem =~ /\A[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+\Z/
  arr << elem if val == 0
end

len = arr.length - 1

if arr.length > 4
  str = ""
  i = 0
  while i < len do 
    if arr[i..i+3].length == 4
      str << arr[i..i+2].join + "-"
      i += 3
    elsif arr[i..i+2].length == 3
      str << arr[i..i+1].join + "-"
      i += 2
    elsif arr[i..i+1].length == 2
      str << arr[i..i+1].join
      i += 2
    elsif !arr[i].nil?
      str << arr[i]
      i += 1
    end
  end
  puts str
else
  if arr.length <= 3
    puts arr.join
  else
    puts arr[0..1].join + "-" + arr[2..3].join
  end
end
```

But none of them is correct

Comment: Why do your approaches do not work? What result do you get from them?

Comment: Both of them didn't work

Comment: Handle `num_of_digits == 1` as a special case before the loop. 2 and 4 are special cases inside the loop. Given any other number of digits, just output 3 digits, and reduce `num_of_digits` by three.

Comment: @user3386109 Can you explain with a code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the function invoice_number in python

```
def invoice_number(invoice):
    s = ''.join(x for x in invoice if x <= '9' and x >= '0')
    n = len(s)
    if n <= 3:
        return s

    w = ''
    i = 0
    while i + 3 <= n:
        for j in range(0, 3):
            w += s[i + j]
        i += 3
        w += ('-')
    m = n - i
    if m ==  0: return w[:-1]
    if m == 1: return w[:m-3] + '-' + s[-2:]
    return w + s[i:]
```

Testing

```
print(invoice_number('1234567'))
print(invoice_number('12345678'))
print(invoice_number('abc123456789'))
print(invoice_number('1234abc5678xyz9foobar'))

123-45-67
123-456-78
123-456-789
123-456-789
```

Comment: Can you indent your program because it is giving me wrong ouput

Comment: https://gist.github.com/aniketstiwari/fb860557e029301c7a03ea703b943c5c

Comment: @AST Thank you. I managed to two screw up this while trying to beautify it. Fixed

Comment: @YuriGinsburg Looks like the code isn't working. I copy pasted: https://onecompiler.com/python/3whqxzgcv and it didn't gave me right results. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Abhishek You are missing nothing. I fixed this peace of code again, please try again. P. S. OP's code is in Ruby.

Comment: @yuri thanks! Yes, I know it is in ruby. Hence I edited the question and added the tag :,-)

Answer (score 1):

Eliminating non-digits is easy with `re`. For your format, the key is to figure our the "right" splitting indices.

Here is a try:

```
import re

def splits(n, k):
    idx = [(i, min(n, i+k)) for i in range(0, n, k)]
    if len(idx) > 1:
        (a, b), (c, d) = idx[-2:]
        if d - c < 2:
            idx[-2:] = [(a, b - 1), (c - 1, d)]
    return idx

def myformat(s):
    s = re.sub(r'[^0-9]+', '', s)
    parts = [s[a:b] for a, b in splits(len(s), 3)]
    return '-'.join(parts)
```

Tests:

```
>>> myformat('123')
123

>>> myformat('1234')
12-34

>>> myformat('6')
6

>>> myformat('7839072345')
783-907-23-45
```

Answer (score 1):

As the question was asked for `ruby`, adding solution for `ruby`. (The inspiration of the code is mostly from `@yuri` answer)

```
def format_invoice(invoice)
    # only numbers are allowed
    invoice = invoice.tr("^0-9","")
    #puts invoice
    
    return invoice if(invoice.length <= 3)
    formatted_invoice = ''
    i = 0
    # Loop to divide the invoice in group of 3
    while i + 3 <= invoice.length do
        for j in 0..2 do
            formatted_invoice += invoice[i + j]
        end
        i += 3
        formatted_invoice += ('-')
    end
    m = invoice.length - i
    return formatted_invoice[0..-2] if m ==  0
    return formatted_invoice[0..m-4] + '-' + invoice[-2..-1] if m == 1
    return formatted_invoice + invoice[i..-1]
end
```

Testing

```
puts format_invoice('abc1')                      # 1
puts format_invoice('abc123')                    # 123
puts format_invoice('abc123A4')                  # 12-34   
puts format_invoice('1234567')                   # 123-45-67  
puts format_invoice('12345678')                  # 123-456-78
puts format_invoice('abc123456789')              # 123-456-789
puts format_invoice('1234a#c5678xyz9foobar')     # 123-456-789
```